# Setting environmental variable in batch as a path (not working for me) on Windows

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, system

I want to set my folder C:\Users\scruff\Desktop\MinGW2\Cross as variable PREFIX

So I type:

```
set PREFIX=C:\Users\scruff\Desktop\MinGW2\Cross
```

But then when I do:

```
cd PREFIX
```

I get

```
"The system cannot find the specified path".
```

When I do

```
echo %PREFIX%
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\scruff\Desktop\MinGW2\Cross
```

when is do:

```
cd C:\Users\scruff\Desktop\MinGW2\Cross
```

it takes me to the cross directory fine.

:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cd %prefix%`.

DOS/Windows batch files aren't really very clever, you might want to investigate Powershell as an alternative: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419

Comment: Oh ok. That works. Thank you. btw, I cant use powershell because I need this script to be portable.

Comment: Portable where? Powershell is installed as standard on Windows machines from Vista onwards.

Comment: I need to take it on XP machines. And also some administrators disable .Net runtime on vista/7.